# can't install @angular/cli properly

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

npm install is crashing on:

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

I tryied to uninstall it several time with cash clean and then install it back with @angular/cli and it's always crashes.

```
dmitri@dmitri-thinkpad-e570:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/bn.js-a9de3ac3/lib/bn.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/async-test.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-4b3dbb2d/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-media-query.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-notification.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-notification.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dotjs/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dotjs/_formatLimit.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-media-query.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dotjs/patternRequired.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-shadydom.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/dts.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dotjs/switch.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/webapis-shadydom.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/json.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dot'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/wtf.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/dts.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/wtf.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/dts.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dot'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/zone-bluebird.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/json.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/task-tracking.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging//src/serializers/json.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ajv-keywords-e7de9002/keywords/dot'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/zone-bluebird.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/task-tracking.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/zone-error.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/sync-test.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-57ade097/js/browser/bluebird.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/zone-error.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/proxy.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/zone.js-071eb577/dist/zone-mix.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-db-e3ba940e/.editorconfig'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 (node_modules//node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/node-sass-d131eca4'

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/url-loader/-/url-loader-0.6.2.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/dmitri/.npm/_logs/2017-10-30T12_53_53_219Z-debug.log
supporting information:
```

- npm -v prints: 5.5.1
- node -v prints: 8.7.0
- npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/
- ubuntu 16.04

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM "ENOENT: no such file or directory error" when installing Sails.js dependencies with Node 8.9.4 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384811/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-installing-sails-js-dependenc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your **node_modules** dir completely, then run this again `sudo npm install`

Then you can try this if needs be:

To install **@angular/cli** locally run `npm install @angular/cli --save`, while to install it globally run `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

But if it requires a root access, then you have to include the `sudo` which will then be `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Or check your network connection (Internet) as the case might be.

I hope this helps

Comment: I want to install @angular/cli (not angular-cli).

Comment: thanks I already solve this problem. It was strange, a network problem. on other WiFi It was just simple as it have to be. thanks

Comment: oh great to hear that!