# NPM "ENOENT: no such file or directory error" when installing Sails.js dependencies with Node 8.9.4 LTS

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I recently upgraded my computer and with it, to the latest LTS version of Node and NPM:

- Node.js 8.9.4
- NPM 5.6.0

I have a Sails.js 0.12.14 application for which I'm trying to install NPM dependencies with `npm install` but when I do that, I get the following errors:

```
➜  web-service git:(feature/auth) ✗ npm install
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/pako-660dbb41/package.json'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/pako-660dbb41/README.md'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/pako-660dbb41/LICENSE'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/pako-660dbb41/index.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/pako-660dbb41/CHANGELOG.md'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/camelCase.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/uniqueId.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/bindKey.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/unnest.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/bindAll.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/unset.js'
// a bunch of similar Lodash errors removed from here
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/T.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/zipWith.js'
WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/lodash-6e6c9f2a/fp/lastIndexOfFrom.js'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: oauth-sign@0.8.2 (node_modules/oauth-sign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/oauth-sign-b13c86db'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: mkdirp@0.5.1 (node_modules/mkdirp):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-c94c8047'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@0.0.8 (node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/minimist-ba966a6e'

npm ERR! path /Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/sails-02afd14e/node_modules/@sailshq/body-parser
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/sails-02afd14e/node_modules/@sailshq/body-parser' -> '/Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/node_modules/.staging/@sailshq/body-parser-6d1e8405'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Nag/.npm/_logs/2018-01-22T14_40_13_889Z-debug.log
```

I can't seem to figure out what's going on and can't find suitable answers anywhere else online. I even ran `npm cache clean --force`, `rm -rf node_modules` and retried with similar errors. It seemed to work fine when I was on Node ~6 but after upgrading to Node 8.9.4 and NPM 5.6.0, it just won't install my dependencies. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While doing npm install getting an error as "No such file or directory open"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789711/while-doing-npm-install-getting-an-error-as-no-such-file-or-directory-open)

Answer (score 139):

Try deleting the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: I have the same issue but there is no package-lock.json

Comment: Weird. I assumed `package-lock.json` would fix itself instead of giving such a cryptic indirect error, but this indeed fixes that error o_o.

Comment: we get this same thing - deleteing package-lock does "fix" the issue but prevents us from using locks. It has something to do with mapped file system permissions I think.

Comment: Nice! can you elaborate on why this is the solution? i mean what is exactly the problem here and why deleting this file is helping?

Comment: Let me begin by stating that **no** elaborate engineering when into this, but here is my guess. According to the docs `package-lock.json` " It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates." So there as an issue with that particular version of sails, but that specific version was locked in by package-lock.json. By deleting the file npm can now install an updated version that has the issue fixed.... Again this is just a guess so keep that mind.

Comment: Doesn't deleting package-lock.json defeat the purpose of having package-lock.json?

Answer (score 34):

For me, it turned out these errors were hiding the real underlying problem, which was that my credentials for a third-party npm repository (azure devops) had expired. I had to re-run `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc` to update the token in my `.npmrc` file.

Comment: thanks for this, expired token was the reason for me as well

Comment: This answer is actually the only one which really addresses the issue and doesn't only guess about solving-strategies!

Comment: Thanks for this. This was my issue too, I didn't have my `.npmrc` configured for Gitlab.

Answer (score 22):

No permission, no internet issue, it's just a general issue of `npm`.
I solved the problem with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/).

```
yarn install
```

Or you can use `no-optional` flag.

```
npm install --no-optional
```

Answer (score 15):

It may be a problem with the cache, try to verify the cache.

```
npm cache verify
```

Comment: This solved my issue, no idea why...

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I tried deleting `package-lock.json`, clearing and verifing the npm cache, removing `node_modules`, even stopping the antivirus (W10 machine) and was still getting this error.

I somehow fixed it by running `npm update` before `npm install`, which creates a new `package-lock.json`:

```
del /f package-lock.json
rd /s /q node_modules
npm cache clean
npm cache verify
npm update
npm install
```

Comment: After searching for hours together,this is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` is required for npm v6+

Answer (score 10):

Deleting and regenerating 'package-lock.json' usually solves this issue however that's inherently risky because you will likely be upgrading multiple packages at a time.

In my case it turned out that there was one specific package version that package-lock.json was referencing, that was 5 levels deep in the dependency. That version no longer existed at the npm registry so it caused the install to break. I had to find which package was pulling in this dependency and upgrade that one to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you give more details as to how you went about this process please?

Comment: now i can't remember if there was a specific error that led me to the problemactic package, but there are some troubleshooting steps and tools that might help:

First try this:
Delete 'Node_modules'. Run 'npm i' again. Check logs for any indication of problems concerning specific packages.

helpful commands:
npm ls - generate a visual dependency tree (including sub dependencies)
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html

npm audit - find vulnerable dependencies
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Last resort: delete package-lock.json (or yarn lock) and run 'npm i'.

Answer (score 5):

- Delete node_modules
- Just delete `package-lock.json` file and then install packages you want with `npm install` . All will work.

  `rm -rf node_modules`

  `rm package-lock.json`

  `npm install`
- If the issue still persists check if you have a global version of any of the packages installed.
  This can happen if you have a global version of a package that clashes with a local version of a package.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when I was on Node.js 12 attempting to run `npm install` against a `package-lock.json` generated using Node.js 16.

Switching back to Node.js 16 resolved the issue:

```
nvm use 16
```

Of course, deleting the `package-lock.json` would have also resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This seems like a probable cause in certain scenarios. I'm currently working on upgrading a repo from Node v12 to v16, and it's possible a mismatch popped up along the way.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this for awhile, and it seems be be related to the following.

Let's say you have 3 modules, A, B and C

Module A includes B and C directly
Module B also includes module C, in it's package.json dependencies.

If your package.json dependencies in module A look like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
     "C": "^1.0.0",
     "B": "^1.1.0"
}
```

You will get the above error you mentioned, ENOENT, blah, blah in .staging

If on the other hand you include the module with the nested include first like:

```
"dependencies": {
     "B": "^1.1.0",
     "C": "^1.0.0"
}
```

The error goes away.  This seems like a bug in npm with nested dependencies, and the error messages and logs were not very descriptive.  Check your dependency tree and see if you have the described case, if so, that is your issue.

Comment: BTW, after doing the above, my package-lock.json files now work.   Before I made sure all my dependencies were ordered as such, I no longer have to remove my package-lock.json files to get it to work.

Comment: Could you provide more details as to how to go about this process? How do you descover which modules depend on which etc?

Comment: The above worked for a bit and then came back again, after some of my team added more dependencies.  One of the problems seems to be that npm installs dependencies asynchronously and depending on how you nest your dependencies, it fails in random places (because of a race condition between the async threads).  For example, in the above example, if module C starts installing, then B starts installing, B will fail because it's trying to install C, which is also installing as a result of A.  I just could never get npm to work 100% of the time, I switched to yarn, and have not had a problem since.

Comment: @LeighBicknell little late reply but for future readers you can use `npm ls name-of-package` which will show you the dependency tree

Answer (score 3):

Just delete `package-lock.json` file and then install package(s) you want. All will work.

Answer (score 2):

I have presented this same error due to npm cache problems. Run

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside removing `package-lock.json` I had to remove `node_modules` so `package-lock.json` could be generated in the right way

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have `package-lock.json` or `package.json` under your working folder, call `npm init` first.

Answer (score 0):

#### Checkout package-lock.json from upstream and re-run `npm install`

I'm dealing with this issue right now, and it seems to have something to do with the way `package-lock.json` gets generated.

The problem finally resolved itself when I checked out `package-lock.json` from my team's upstream repository and re-ran `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

### A quick checklist to solve this issue

- Verify you are in the right directory with a correctly initialised `npm` project.
- Verify you are using the correct `Node` and `npm` versions for your project then retrying `npm i`
- Try deleting `package-lock.json` and then `npm i`.Keep in mind simply deleting `package-lock.json` outright might not work for some cases due to people relying on the lock behaviour, but it can lead you to the root cause.
- Once you find the root cause and solve it, you can always revert back to the old `package-lock.json`
- Verify if you are using any private packages in your `package.json`. Depending on the package the `~/.npmrc` file might be missing or incorrectly configured.
- Always be wary when deleting and regenerating `package-lock.json` as it can cause some confusing bugs sometimes.

### Issue in my case

- I was missing the `~/.npmrc` file which would throw the `npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory` error when running `npm i` for a project that used private packages.
- Deleting the `package-lock.json` and running `npm i` threw this error.

```
npm ERR! 404  '@aPrivatePackage@^2.36.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'myProject'
```

- At this point it was clear I had to configure my `.npmrc` for this to work correctly as the private package required doing so.
- After setting up my `.npmrc` and restoring the previous lock file `npm i` then worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced it with this issue when creating new react app via terminal.

For solving this problem;

I've previously installed create-react-app globally. I uninstall the package to ensure npx always uses the latest version of create-react-app.

To uninstall, run this command: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

After that, try to create new react app via `npx create-react-app my-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the following:

1. `.npmrc` contains valid credentials & complete list of repos URL to download the required modules
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file
3. Directory where `npm install` is being run, make sure it has write
   permission

Answer (score 0):

you could try run :

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

on your CMD if the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just freshly installed NPM on windows, then check the following if you are getting a not found error:

- Go to you APP Data Roaming("C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming")
- Check if the folder npm exists
- If it does not exist, just create a new empty NPM folder

Now try create your application again i.e:

```
npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-dashboard --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/dashboard/starter-example"
```