# Error Message is popping in cmd while installing appium through npm in windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

I try to install appium with npm on Windows 10 CMD but I get the following error messages:

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\bplist-creator-30ee61c3\test\sample1.bplist'
>   npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\bplist-creator-30ee61c3\test\sample2.bplist'
>   npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\bplist-creator-30ee61c3\test\uid.bplist'
>   npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\bplist-creator-30ee61c3\test\utf16.bplist'
>   npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Please add more context and explanation to your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM "ENOENT: no such file or directory error" when installing Sails.js dependencies with Node 8.9.4 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384811/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-installing-sails-js-dependenc)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some packages.

1. Make sure that your `package.json` has listed all your dependencies
2. Run npm install
   If the issues still persists

   - Run `npm install`
   - Run `npm cache clean`
   - Run `npm install -g npm`
   - Rub `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve that issue by following methods:

Just type `npm install` and hit Enter.
    Check issue still exists. and If issue not resolved, continue these methods.
    type `npm cache clean` and hit Enter
    type `sudo npm install -g npm` and hit Enter.
    Retry `npm install` and hit Enter.

If you are behind the company network proxy you can execute the following command on CMD:
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyip:port/