# How to fix 'npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory' on every file

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying out a Resume Creator [from Github](https://github.com/salomonelli/best-resume-ever). It calls for npm install, but when i run it, it outputs multiple error messages such as: npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting material-design-icons@3.0.1: and (this shows up hundreds of times, with different files) npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\best-resume-ever\node_modules.staging\rxjs-7f4abf76_esm5\internal\operators\findIndex.js.map'

I have tried reinstalling Node, clearing cache, I'm aware that I'm behind a proxy, but I've worked around it. I've tried cloning the git onto another drive, still no change. Other project work fine.

I expected a finished npm install with no errors, acutal output was a long list of "npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open "path"

Comment: I just tried and it works fine for me. Try deleting `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Hello. There is  no package-lock.json in my directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM "ENOENT: no such file or directory error" when installing Sails.js dependencies with Node 8.9.4 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384811/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-installing-sails-js-dependenc)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have git installed on your machine? If you don't, you need to install [it](https://git-scm.com/downloads) from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Check your error log again. If you have this error near the bottom of your log, you definitely need to install git.

```
 npm ERR! syscall spawn git
```