# ENOENT: no such file or directory when running npm install command

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I run `npm install`, I getting the following error,

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Live Project\insyte-mobile\insyte-mobile\node_modules.staging\core-js-c9f4d03d\library\fn\symbol\unscopables.js'

Here is a screen shoot of the error
[image: Error screenshot]:

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "tonight-mobile",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "initial-android": "npm install && npm run android",
    "initial-ios": "npm install && npm run ios",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^5.0.2",
    "firebase": "^5.7.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-image-picker-form": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.13.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-persist-filesystem-storage": "^1.3.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  }
}
```

above is the package.json file.

I have also used another code of this project, but this time I'm getting following error :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the same directory where also you `package.json` is in?

Comment: Yes. I am sure.

Comment: Then post the entire error message and also you package.json

Comment: it’s just a warning though; does it affect the actual build / install result, and how?

Comment: Please do not paste screen shots in the future. You kill your own question with it, just copy and paste the text.. I opened up a bug upstream to track this, my answer will track the answer the upstream devs provide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM "ENOENT: no such file or directory error" when installing Sails.js dependencies with Node 8.9.4 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384811/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-installing-sails-js-dependenc)

Comment: In my case, My hdd got full and that's why it was unable to install the dependencies

Answer (score 30):

First delete the `package-lock.json` and then try `npm install`

Answer (score 11):

Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json, then run `npm install`

Comment: Getting same issue.

Comment: Try to move then the project to the path which does not have any whitespaces: "D:\Live Project\" -> "D:\Projects\".

If this does not help, please do `ls -la`  on your project folder where you do the "npm install" command

Comment: Ok, I'll try this.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is

- Open a terminal in your pc's root and run this command:

  `killall node`
- Before restart the new metro bundler please reinstall the dependencies on yarn or npm :

  `npm i OR yarn`

Also the article:  **[ENOENT: no such file](https://freakycoder.com/react-native-notes-4-error-bundling-failed-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-uv-cwd-c8581a2339c0)**

Answer (score 2):

Follow this step:

1. Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file
2. Run this command:
   `npm cache clean -force`
3. Then run this command:
   `npm install` (if the issue is not yet fixed try the following 4th step.)
4. Run this command `npm install -g npm`,then `npm install`
5. Finally run this command: `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution for this error:

> "npm WARN tar ENOENT:no such file or directory

Not only for ENOENT if all files in npm modules shows this kinds of error.

1. Go to your command prompt
2. Check for npm version(`npm -v`)
3. If its giving a version then type command `npm init` and click on enter for whatever it asks
4. After completing all the steps and then again try to create one angular project. It will be created without any errors in node modules.

Answer (score 1):

The "solutions" in anything I found online are not actually solutions

I Followed these steps.

1. Delete package-lock.json works but is a very weak workaround as the package-lock.json is an important file that shouldn't need to be deleted.
2. Follow the below command

> rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force

3. Now run `npm i` .

Answer (score 0):

Please check your current working directory. if you have created project using
npx react-native init demo

then navigate inside project from terminal using
cd demo
npm install

will install all npm modules and you can also check installed packages in the directory: demo/node_modules

also if project is expo base then
run expo eject to eject from expo

Comment: I'm new to React Native, So can you please explain me how to check that the project created using npx or expo,

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started
then details here as - Creating a new application  


npx react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

Check the node version, if the application was build using an older node version then you can downgrade your local environment node version using NVM (node version manager).

Answer (score -1):

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\Projects\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Projects\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Solution ==> Check the root directory you might be outside the root directory or in wrong folder path has been opened

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you do not have [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) installed on your computer. This is particularly true if you are getting this error at the bottom of your log:

```
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
```

If so, then you need to install git from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads.

I had the same problem as you, and once I installed git, the problem went away.

Answer (score -3):

Do you have a **package.json** file in the folder ?*

To run npm install you need to have a **package.json** file.

Comment: Yes, I have package.json