# Peer dependencies error messages on Angular: "None of them installed

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, npm-install, peer

**Goal**: I try to update and add peer dependencies according to the error I got.

I expect the peer error messages to be gone but they are still there.

Error Messages:

> npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/architect@>=0.800.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@>=8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@>=8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I tried the following commands:

`npm install --save-dev "@angular-devkit/architect@>=0.800.0"`

`npm install --save-dev "@angular-devkit/schematics@>=8.0.0"`

`npm install --save-dev "@angular-devkit/core@>=8.0.0"`

I also (After Shashank wrote me on the reply) deleted package-json.lock. Then typed the command "npm i" and got many messages such:
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\web development\projects\frontend current  backup 8 - Copy\urigrossltdWebsite\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist' -> 'C:\web development\projects\frontend current  backup 8 - Copy\urigrossltdWebsite\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules.yallist.DELETE'

package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "urigrossltd",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "@material/button": "^5.1.0",
    "@material/icon-button": "^5.1.0",
    "@material/toolbar": "^2.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.2",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-animations": "0.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3",
    "slidetoggle": "^1.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
    "acorn": "^7.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.8.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check and update question with the version which is there in package.json after running this command ? BTW, you can also check the exact version on `package-lock.json` file. Sometimes, its also safe to delete to delete  `package-lock.json` and do `npm i`

Comment: After deleting package-lock.json and did npm i : I noticed that it wrote me many lines such: npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\web development\projects\frontend current  backup 8 - Copy\urigrossltdWebsite\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'C:\web development\projects\frontend current  backup 8 - Copy\urigrossltdWebsite\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.wrappy.DELETE'    

What should I do next?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384811/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-installing-sails-js-dependenc . give a try to its answers and let me know if it solved this

Comment: Ok, what about the peer dependencies error messages that refusing to go away?
npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/architect@>=0.800.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@>=8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN angular-cli-ghpages@0.6.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@>=8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Ohhh.... is it still coming ? After deleting `lock` file and doing `npm i` with `"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.901.0",` etc in package.json ? are u sure you are doing `ng s` in proper project ? This does not make sense. I hope its not a `npm package` for other project where you need to add it in `dependency`  . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies

Comment: Can you confirm that you have directory created for all 3 under `node_modules` such as  `C:\YOUR_PROJ\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect` and so on ?

Comment: for example it write the command : npm i @angular-devkit/schematics@>=8.0.0
I get the message:
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-26T18_07_36_438Z-debug.log



Then package-lock.json created inside:
@angular-devkit/schematics": {
      "version": "9.1.3",

Seems like schematics version is updated but i still get the message :  @angular-devkit/schematics@>=8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: On lock file I saw the latest version. But still I get the same message. I tried it on Schematics dependency

On windows explorer i cannot see the folder @angular-devkit under node_modules at all. I can see it only on the vs-code explorer. Is it ok?  

see link with the screenshot. Thank you for helping :)  https://ibb.co/pP3wfjK

Comment: I do not see any link for screenshot in either comment or question. Can you see any relevant error in `2020-04-26T18_07_36_438Z-debug.log` ? It must be having some more details of this error

Comment: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined Was in the log twice.

I also attaching the log here https://shrib.com/#LavaGull6Gebj7k  

Maybe my package.json  is messed up?

Comment: Uri: As one last try. Can you delete `node_module` folder entirely and `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` . Last time I didnt ask you to delete the node_modules folder. Also, if that does not fix,  can u try the same thing on some fresh workspace. I am sorry for guessing so many things. This is weird issue

Comment: Thank you @ShashankVivek but this is still doesn't work after deleting node_module, package-lock and then npm i. 
By the way, when doing ng s  it compiled all the modules as es5. It apparently unrelated to the current issue.

 I appreciate your efforts to help me - Stay safe :)